# Error "Requested listen uri scheme must be http, but was https" using C#,WCS,Apache,Mono,Debian for Rest-Service

Tags: c#, wcf, mono, apache2, debian

recently I startet to create a Rest-Service in C# (WCF Service Application). The aim is to use it on a Debian 7-System with apache2 + mod-mono + https + basic auth. Everything was working with http. But I can do what I want.. it won't work with https. I allways get the error-message "Requested listen uri scheme must be http, but was https." and don't understand what is wrong. I think I did everything as described in various blogs and tutorials in the web.

I correctly configured https, created the self signed certificiate etc. and, in fact, https itself is working as it should. But not with the service. I also tried to use the service with https on my Win7-Machine with IIS-Express 7.5 which worked like a charm. It has to be somethin about Linux/Mono/Apache.

Below are my config-files. I hope someone can help me :(

Greetings daily

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true"
             targetFramework="4.0">
  </compilation>
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5"
       clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="RestService.RestServiceImpl"
           behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">

    <endpoint address=""
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="RestService.IRestServiceImpl"
              bindingConfiguration="webHttpTransportSecurity"
              behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBindingBehavior" />

  </service>

</services>


<bindings>

  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpTransportSecurity">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>

</bindings>


<behaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"
                       httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttpBindingBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

</behaviors>

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>

</system.serviceModel>

<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  </modules>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

**Site-Config for Apache**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
SSLOptions StrictRequire
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2

MonoServerPath wcs.mydomain.de "/usr/bin/mod-mono-server4"
MonoDebug wcs.mydomain.de true
MonoSetEnv wcs.mydomain.de  MONO_IOMAP=all
MonoAutoApplication  disabled
MonoApplications wcs.mydomain.de "/api:/var/www/wcs"

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

<Location /api>
    SSLRequireSSL
    Options FollowSymLinks

    Allow from all
    Order allow,deny

    MonoSetServerAlias wcs.mydomain.de
    SetHandler mono

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Authorization required"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT**

Additional Information, hoping someone can make use of it and see my fault.

**Version Information**

```
Version information: Mono Runtime Version: 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-8); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.1
```

**Complete Stacktrace**

```
System.ArgumentException: Requested listen uri scheme must be http, but was https.
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Http.HttpChannelListener`1[System.ServiceModel.Channels.IReply    Channel]..ctor (System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpTransportBindingElement source,   System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpTransportBindingElement.BuildChannelListener[IReplyChannel    ] (System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext.BuildInnerChannelListener[IReplyChannel]      () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingElement.BuildChannelListener[IReplyChannel]     (System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WebMessageEncodingBindingElement.BuildChannelListener[IReplyCh    annel] (System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext context) [0x00000] in <filename      unknown>:0 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext.BuildInnerChannelListener[IReplyChannel]      () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding.BuildChannelListener[IReplyChannel] (System.Uri      listenUriBaseAddress, System.String listenUriRelativeAddress, ListenUriMode listenUriMode,      System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection parameters) [0x00000] in <filename      unknown>:0 
at System.ServiceModel.DispatcherBuilder.BuildListener      (System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint se,       System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection pl) [0x00000] in <filename      unknown>:0 
at System.ServiceModel.DispatcherBuilder.BuildChannelDispatcher (System.Type      serviceType, System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint se,      System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection commonParams) [0x00000] in      <filename unknown>:0 
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime () [0x00000] in <filename      unknown>:0 
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen (TimeSpan timeout) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open (TimeSpan timeout) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SvcHttpHandler.EnsureServiceHostCore () [0x00000] in  <filename unknown>:0 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SvcHttpHandler.EnsureServiceHost () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SvcHttpHandler.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.HttpApplication+<Pipeline>c__Iterator6.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.Tick () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

**IRestServiceImpl.cs**

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace RestService
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRestServiceImpl
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "info")]
        string Info();
    }
}
```

**RestServiceImpl.svc**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="RestService.RestServiceImpl" CodeBehind="RestServiceImpl.svc.cs" %>
```

**RestServiceImpl.svc.cs**

```
namespace RestService
{
    public class RestServiceImpl : IRestServiceImpl
    {
        #region IRestServiceImpl Members

        public string Info()
        {
            return "This is the Rest-Service for a WCS";
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**mod_mono.conf**

```
AddType application/x-asp-net .svc .aspx .ashx .asmx .ascx .asax .config
DirectoryIndex index.aspx
Include /etc/mono-server4/mono-server4-hosts.conf
```

**EDIT-2**

As knocte suggested below I upgraded to Mono 3 but still get the same error.

```
System.ArgumentException - Requested listen uri scheme must be http, but was https.
```

**Version Information**

```
Version Information: 3.0.12 (master/574dbc8 Wed May 29 20:34:12 CEST 2013); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.17020
```

**Stacktrace**

```
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Http.HttpChannelListener`1[System.ServiceModel.Channels.IReplyChannel]..ctor (System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpTransportBindingElement source, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext context) [0x00126] in /opt/mono-3.0/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels.Http/HttpChannelListener.cs:71 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpTransportBindingElement.BuildChannelListener[IReplyChannel] (System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext context) [0x00000] in /opt/mono-3.0/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/HttpTransportBindingElement.cs:246 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext.BuildInnerChannelListener[IReplyChannel] () [0x00020] in /opt/mono-3.0/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/BindingContext.cs:161 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingElement.BuildChannelListener[IReplyChannel] (System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext context) [0x00011] in /opt/mono-3.0/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/BindingElement.cs:63 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WebMessageEncodingBindingElement.BuildChannelListener[IReplyChannel] (System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext context) [0x0001d] in /opt/mono-3.0/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel.Web/System.ServiceModel.Channels/WebMessageEncodingBindingElement.cs:126 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext.BuildInnerChannelListener[IReplyChannel] () [0x00020] in /opt/mono-3.0/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/BindingContext.cs:161 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding.BuildChannelListener[IReplyChannel] (System.Uri listenUriBaseAddress, System.String listenUriRelativeAddress, ListenUriMode listenUriMode, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection parameters) [0x00046] in /opt/mono-3.0/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/Binding.cs:174 
at System.ServiceModel.DispatcherBuilder.BuildListener (System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint se, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection pl) [0x00038] in /opt/mono-3.0/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ServiceHostBase.cs:720 
at System.ServiceModel.DispatcherBuilder.BuildChannelDispatcher (System.Type serviceType, System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint se, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection commonParams) [0x0005e] in /opt/mono-3.0/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ServiceHostBase.cs:657 
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime () [0x000ad] in /opt/mono-3.0/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ServiceHostBase.cs:460 
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen (TimeSpan timeout) [0x00006] in /opt/mono-3.0/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ServiceHostBase.cs:567 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open (TimeSpan timeout) [0x00006] in /opt/mono-3.0/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/CommunicationObject.cs:170 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open () [0x00000] in /opt/mono-3.0/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/CommunicationObject.cs:164 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SvcHttpHandler.EnsureServiceHostCore () [0x00068] in /opt/mono-3.0/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/SvcHttpHandler.cs:138 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SvcHttpHandler.EnsureServiceHost () [0x00016] in /opt/mono-3.0/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/SvcHttpHandler.cs:117 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SvcHttpHandler.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] in /opt/mono-3.0/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/SvcHttpHandler.cs:75 
at System.Web.HttpApplication+<Pipeline>c__Iterator3.MoveNext () [0x00dd7] in /opt/mono-3.0/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:1368 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.Tick () [0x00000] in /opt/mono-3.0/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:932
```

Comment: Addition: Recently I talked to a real Linux/Apache etc. crack and showed him my configuration, certificate and so on. He didn't see anything strange and mentioned that it looks like the problem is only caused by the mono-backend which assumes to get http requests but in fact gets https requests. But I don't have any idea how to tell the mono-server/backend that it is ok to take https-requests..

Comment: Mono 2.x is too old to handle WCF properly, upgrade to Mono 3.x and test again

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'll try it this evening and tell you if it worked.

Comment: @knocte 

Hi knocte, I upgraded to Mono 3. Version information is now 3.0.12 (master/574dbc8 Wed May 29 20:34:12 CEST 2013); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.17020. But I still get the same error :(

Comment: then I would recommend filing a bug in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: Same issue here, Mono 2.8. App works in win8 desktop, but not mono.  Did you file a bug?  I would like to watch it.

Comment: Hi there Travis. I'm sorry to tell you that I didn't file a bug. I was in a hurry and couldn't wait for a maybe bugfix. I tried to use ServiceStack instead of plain mod_mono which now works like a charm. I would suggest you give ServiceStack a try if it is an option. If you wan't to file a bug you aure free to use my data from above if you want.